# Issue in drop multiple pins in google map in coordinator

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-maps, google-maps-markers

i want to drop multiple pin in google map with dynamic value so below is my code .

**VIEW**

```
<html>
<head><?php echo $map['js']; ?></head>
<body><?php echo $map['html']; ?></body>
```

**Controller**

```
function index(){

 $address ="Gondal Road, Dr. Yagnik Road Corner, Near Malaviya Petrol Pump,      Rajkot, Gujarat 360001";// Google HQ
 $prepAddr = str_replace(' ','+',$address);
 $geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$prepAddr.'&sensor=false');
 $output= json_decode($geocode);
 $lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
 $long = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

 $this->load->library('googlemaps');

 $config['center'] = '37.4419, -122.1419';
 $config['zoom'] = 'auto';
 $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);

 $marker = array();
 $marker['position'] = $lat.','.$long;
 $marker['infowindow_content'] = $address;
 $marker['icon'] = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart? chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=A|9999FF|000000';
 $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);

$marker = array();
$marker['position'] = '37.409, -122.1319';
$marker['draggable'] = TRUE;
$marker['animation'] = 'DROP';
$this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);

$marker = array();
$marker['position'] = '37.449, -122.1419';
$marker['onclick'] = 'alert("You just clicked me!!")';
$this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
$data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();



 $this->load->view('test',$data);

}
```

When i run above code only single pin is drop but i want multiple pins with dynamic value so how can i make it possible ? your all suggestion will be appreciable .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace Your Code With this code:

**Controller:**

```
    $address[ ]=Your multiple address  //store your multiple address in array
    foreach($address as $add)
    {

        $prepAddr = str_replace(' ','+',$add);
        $geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$prepAddr.'&sensor=false');
        $output= json_decode($geocode);
        $lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
        $long = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

        $marker = array();
        $marker['position'] = $lat.','.$long;
        $marker['infowindow_content'] = '$add';
        $marker['icon'] = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=A|9999FF|000000';
        $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
    }
    $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();
    $this->load->view('test',$data);
```

Your view is perfect no need to change.